# I canceled Ubuntu installation and got back to Ubuntu desktop window?

Tags: system-installation, root, usb-installation

I wanted to install Ubuntu, and when I reached the step which asks me 3 main options for installing the OS.

Like in the following picture:

[image]

So I chose the last one as I wanted to put it in a 20GB partition I got from shrinking my 512GB SSD in Windows 10. But when I chose that partition it said that as I remember there's no installation root or something I forgot.

And then as I didn't want to install it alongside windows which I liked but when I chose that earlier, it said it would change some rooting stuff so I canceled that option.

Then I chose quit the installation, and then I got back to Ubuntu desktop !!

I don't understand what's going on actually, is ubuntu now installed in my SSD ? or what exactly ?

Comment: Based upon the picture you provided, nothing is installed. You have not told the installer where to install yet. 20GB is a bit small.

Answer (score 3):

You are in Ubuntu live desktop. After quitting the installation, kindly reboot the device to return to windows.

Comment: And remove the USB